# AWS and Linode server for web application

Tags: amazon-ec2, vps, linode

I think I am failing to understand the benefit of AWS EC2. I am working towards making a web application, and might need a VPS.

From what I have read:

- AWS EC2 is more expensive than a fixed VPS, such as Linode
- Linode can be upgraded too

Considering this, why would I choose AWS EC2? Can I use Linode as default, and then use an EC2 instance when I have a traffic spike? If so, how would that work? Would I need to launch an EC2 instance on demand with a snapshot of my Linode VPS so that it can do the same job?

Comment: Are you you going to scale out manually? Haha))
Read on this: http://matthewphiong.com/price-war-linode-vs-slicehost-vs-amazon-ec2-vs-rackspace-cloud-servers

Comment: Hopefully not! ) how would automated scaling work?

Comment: This is  how you do it on EC2: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_SetUpASLBApp.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use EC2 instances as part of your service. Your Linode VPS can setup a VPN access to EC2 instances as if they are in the same network. There is a AWS product matching the scenario, it's Amazon **VPC(Virtual Private Cloud)**. See the official guide for details:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario3.html

But the EC2 instance can not use your Linode VPS snapshot, you should use EBS image to launch new EC2 instances.